# Create a Logic Apps Custom Connector Using Azure .NET SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am currently working on a project where I need to create a Logic Apps Custom Connector using the Azure .NET SDK. Despite a thorough search through various documentation, including [the Azure.ResourceManager.Logic package on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Logic/), I have been unable to find a dedicated client in the SDK for managing Logic Apps Custom Connectors.

Furthermore, I am looking to initialize the custom connector with a Swagger file endpoint, similar to the functionality available in the Azure UI.

Could anyone provide guidance or examples of how this can be achieved programmatically using the .NET SDK? Are there any alternative methods or APIs that can be used to create and initialize Logic Apps Custom Connectors using .NET, particularly with a Swagger file endpoint?